# Why does "git push" work after doing "git push origin --delete BRANCHNAME"?

Tags: git, git-push

Sometimes I want to delete the remote branch and then push again,if for instance I have amended a commit locally which had already been pushed. (don't worry, I only do this if I am the only one working on that branch).

After I do "`git push origin --delete BRANCHNAME`", I can simply follow that with a "`git push`".

If the branch has been deleted, why does "`git push`" actually work?
Why do I not need to do a "`git push -u origin BRANCHNAME`" again?

Comment: Because you have deleted the remote branch, but haven't done anything to modify the configuration of your local repository.  Whatever tracking configuration was in place for your current branch still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks)' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867900/why-does-git-push-work-after-doing-git-push-origin-delete-branchname#comment53568996_32867900), here is a repo with a local branch tracking an upstream branch:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\b2dpres>git br -avv
* prez                  13a1c36 [origin/prez] 20150923
```

Pushing the deletion of the branch:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\b2dpres>git push origin --delete prez
To https://VonC@github.com/VonC/b2d.git
 - [deleted]         prez
```

That doesn't change the local config:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\b2dpres>git config --local --get-regexp branch.prez
branch.prez.remote origin
branch.prez.merge refs/heads/prez
```

Nor does it delete the local branch:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\b2dpres>git br -avv
* prez                  13a1c36 [origin/prez: gone] 20150923
```

(Note the "gone")

A simple `git push` will know what to push (the local current branch `prez`) where (to `origin`) and to which branch (to its tracking branch `origin/prez`)

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\b2dpres>git push
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 763.97 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 2), reused 1 (delta 0)
To https://VonC@github.com/VonC/b2d.git
 * [new branch]      prez -> prez
```

It recreates the branch on the remote side.